# How to give a git repo a name?

Tags: git

I am making a remote repo by using these command

```sh
mkdir NewRepo
cd NewRepo
git init
```

Then I clone this repo to local

```sh
git clone user@server:/path/to/app/.git
```

This worked for me, But I want give the repo a name, do something like everybody else does:

```sh
git clone user@server:/path/to/app/reponame.git
```

Is there anyone who can tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to create a git repository directly in a folder, without the subdirectory `.git`. To do this, you do this:

```
mkdir myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git init --bare
```

This is called a bare repository - it contains the contents of what would normally be in a `.git` folder. It has no working copy. These sorts of repositories are usually used in the remote server (where you're pushing your changes); i.e., when your remote repository basically reflects what you've committed locally, and nobody is working directly on the code in the remote server location (therefore no need for a working copy.)

More detail:

1. [Use in distributed workflows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows).
2. [setting up a public repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Answer (score 16):

The *name* is given by the directory, as mentioned above, though it does support given a *description* for software like gitweb:

```
echo "Happy description" >.git/description
```

Answer (score 7):

Repositories don't have names, you just use the folder name (I suppose you could name the folder "app.git":

```
git clone user@server:/path/to/app
```

Remotes do have names, e.g. "origin" or whatever you like. This is up to the client though, not a property of the remote repository.

```
git remote add origin user@server:/path/to/app
```