# Git: what is project.git and how to clone it via SSH from an owned domain

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

This is very stupid (question or git system or git documentation - I still haven't decided).

I have ssh access to client's server. There is a website `domain.com`, and there is `git` repository, they are under `/var/www/html`. In `git` config file there are no remotes, but should they be there? Git itself is installed, I can list history for example.

And subject is the question: at local pc how can I push and pull from that repository? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: it looks like you are missing quite a lot of concept of git. I'd suggest you keep reading the docs and maybe follow a couple of tutorials.

Comment: Have you looked at [Git: The SSH Protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)? Hint: you do not SSH into the server manually.

Comment: Guys, thanks for fast response. The problem is - how to get that repository url, having only domain name and server path to repo (.git folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a remote repository you'd like to work with from your local machine.

#### Cloning

You'll need a copy of that repository in your local machine, otherwise how are you going to work with it, right? Let's have a look at the docs:

> **The SSH Protocol**
>
> A common transport protocol for Git when self-hosting
> is over SSH. This is because SSH access to servers is already set up
> in most places — and if it isn’t, it’s easy to do. SSH is also an
> authenticated network protocol and, because it’s ubiquitous, it’s
> generally easy to set up and use.
>
> To clone a Git repository over SSH, you can specify an `ssh://` URL like
> this:
>
> ```
> $ git clone ssh://[user@]server/project.git
> ```
>
> Or you can use the shorter
> scp-like syntax for the SSH protocol:
>
> ```
> $ git clone [user@]server:project.git
> ```
>
> In both cases above, if you
> don’t specify the optional username, Git assumes the user you’re
> currently logged in as. [[source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)]

In your case, the command should be `ssh://root@domain.com/var/www/html/.git`<sup>1</sup>, as we were able to hammer out in the comments.

This will clone that repository locally and will set your local clone to point to that repository as remote.

> Man, the point is that I have already read that git doc and all related stuff. There is everywhere `project.git` at the end of command, which is repo name I guess.

Now I see the confusion. Typically, a `git` repo locally is cloned as a working copy. A working copy has a root dir and, inside, an hidden `.git` folder. However, [this is not always the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055791/how-to-give-a-git-repo-a-name), as you may [create](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.27.0#_options) a repository as [bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632454/how-do-you-use-git-bare-init-repository). It is a convention (not mandatory as far as I know) to init a bare repository as `repo.git`. A bare repository doesn't possess the hidden `.git` folder and, as such, ".git" is appended to the root folder name. This is why you often see `project.git` in the git documentation.

> In `git` config file there are no remotes, but should they be there?

On the remote, probably no, there shouldn't be any. This isn't a general rule (on the contrary) but from your description should be the best answer. On you local clone, on the contrary, there should be one.

---

<sup>1) This tells us two things: if there *is* a folder `.git` in that location, then your root folder is `html` and everything inside of it is under version control. As a consequence, your remote is set up as a working copy. If this is not the case, since you say you are able to run some git commands in the remote, you might want to [check if the remote is bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830701/how-do-i-check-if-a-repository-is-bare) and troubleshoot the root of that repo using these tools.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do understand this: I need url. Question is - what is that repository url and how can I get it? I have a domain name and a path to website project code on a server, that's it. And that is the point of all this discussion...

Comment: So basically, in this case, clone url would be http(s)://domain.com/.git? Correct? But what about ssh? Clone url would also be (consider I have root access) ssh://root@domain.com:/.git? Correct?

Comment: Http is closed. Man, the point is that I have already read that git doc and all related stuff. There is everywhere `project.git` at the end of command, which is repo name I guess. And it confuses. Where to get repo name, huh? And I also haven't found that full path to `.git` folder - not relative to domain name - should be included after `domain.com` in ssh. The ssh solution is `ssh://root@domain.com/var/www/html/.git` :(

Comment: I finally see your point. Please have a look at my edit. You'll have to find out if you are working with a remote that is a bare repository, _or_ a working copy remote.

Comment: Thanks. It is a working copy. I've cloned successfully and I see all git history locally. So basically now question is solved.